# Number of CPU cores available for a Cloudfoundry application

Tags: cloud-foundry, cpu-cores

I was not able to find relevant information about the **number of CPU cores available for an application instance running on Cloudfoundry**.

Where can I find this information?

Furthermore, how can I **increase the number of CPU cores** available for my Cloudfoundry application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK a DEA instance (a machine which actually run applications) limit CPU usage according to memory requested for an app. E.g. if DEA has 8GB and an application limited to 2GB, the application get “at least 25% of currently available CPU”.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply Alex. You mean a percentage of a core by "25% of currently available CPU"? How can I know for sure that I have for instance 2 cores available for my app?

Comment: I ask this because I want to know exactly how many cores I have available for application/performance tuning purposes...

Comment: @balteo An application works inside a warden container. Resources for the container limited using cgroups kernel feature. For CPU it uses 'shares' concept. I'm not sure about kernels. More information is in Linux kernel documentation I guess.